# Go to specific element C

Tags: c, for-loop, vector, iteration

I want to use a for loop to iterate through vector and when a certain condition is met, I want to go back to a certain element of vector and restart the loop from there.

For example, let's say that my vector is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; and when the first element that is bigger than 5 is met, I want to restart the loop from number 3 again.

This is just an example.

I don't know if I can write something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
{
   if(v[i] > 5)
   {
      i = 3;
   }
}
```

Is this correct? If no, how can I do this using a for loop and the index of the vector?

Comment: You *can* do this. But it is confusing. Maybe you want to share the original problem with us?

Comment: Do you mean to restart from the value `3` or from the 2nd element previous to where the `5` is? Note that your code will be an infinite loop. Another problem is the `i` will be increment from `3` to `4` for the next loop, which is the same element where you found the value `5`, and anyway the `3` is to be found at  `v[2]` not `v[3]`, so you need to set `i = 1`.

Comment: I am intresed only if such thing works. Like setting the i variable to a certain number inside the loop. The problem that I posted is just an example that I used so that my problem is understandable. @EugeneSh.

Comment: In C, that is possible, but you need to ensure you can meet an end condition somehow. It's can be confusing to post "something like my code" because it can raise questions you didn't think you were asking. That's one reason for posting the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to assign a value of choice to a loop variable inside the loop and its behaviour is well defined.

You just have to realise that if this process leads to an infinite loop, you should put a check in place to be able to break out of the loop.